# Why does my frame freeze when I start this action[DOWNLOADING]

Tags: java, jframe, actionlistener

I made a frame with a button "Start downloading" for it to download a JAR from a website.

The problem is whenever I click the start downloading button, the whole frame freezes until it is done downloading, and then it's normal after that.

How would I fix it?

Here's the code when the button is clicked it executes

```
 private void addToDesktop() throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL("urlremoved");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    InputStream inputstream = connection.getInputStream();
    FileSystemView filesys = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
    filesys.getHomeDirectory();
    sizeOfClient = connection.getContentLength();
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedoutputstream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(clientDL.textField1.getText() + "/jarname.jar")));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int length;


    while(( length = inputstream.read(buffer)) > -1)
    {
        down += length;
        bufferedoutputstream.write(buffer, 0 , length);
         String text = clientDL.label1.getText();
        int perc = getPerc();

        if(perc <= 50)
        {
            text +=  getPerc() + "% done";
        }else
        {
            text ="Please wait until the jar is downloading...";
            text = text + (100 - perc) + " % remaining";
        }
    }

    if (down == sizeOfClient) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(clientDL.frame, "Download successful. It has been placed at : " + clientDL.textField1.getText() + "/jarname.jar", "Success!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        clientDL.frame.dispose();
        clientDL.frame.setVisible(false);

    }
    bufferedoutputstream.flush();
    bufferedoutputstream.close();
    inputstream.close();
    hideSplashScreen();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you need to run it on a separate thread if you don't want it to freeze.

There are many ways for implementing this. Almost all requires you to extract the addToDestop() method into a runnable class. This class could extend Thread or SwingWorker or anything of that nature.

You can check the following link for SwingWorker.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/swingworker-137249.html

Following pseudocode would give you an idea.

```
public class Downloader extends SwingWorker<VOID, VOID> {
    private String url;

    public Downloader(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    private void addToDesktop(){
        //your code
    }

    @override
    protected void doInBackground(){
        addToDesktop();
    }

    @override
    protected void done(){
        //success
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello harun , thanks for the short notice reply, how would i go on about doing that? im still new :c thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try using Threads it will stop the freezing of your frame

```
private Thread thread;
```

.

```
thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
//Your code here
}
});
thread.start();
```

Comment: thanks! worked perfectly :) i just had to catch the IOException rather than throwing it.

Comment: -1. Do not update your GUI outside of EDT. And you didn't put that dissclaimer.